# mongo-go-driver projection array length

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to get a projection for the number of elements in a documents array.

```
options.SetProjection(bson.M{
    "foo": true,
    "nrOfBars": bson.M{ "$size": "$bars" },
})
```

`bars` is the fieldname of the array.
This query though always returns 0 instead of the arrays length.

How do I correctly query for the length of the array with the new mongo-go-driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an aggregation operator as part of the projection document. A [projection document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) is for use in simple queries to only return certain fields.

What you want to use is the `$project` stage in an *[aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)*. This is different from a simple projection document, and you are able to use more complex aggregation operators such as `$size`. Here is some example code that I believe does what you would like:

```
ctx := context.TODO()

pipeline := bson.A{
    bson.D{{
        "$project",
        bson.D{
            {"foo", 1},
            {"nrOfBars", bson.D{
                {"$size", "$bar"},
            }},
        },
    }},
}

cur, err := col.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
```

This aggregation returns a cursor. To access the results you must iterate through the cursor as described in the [cursor documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Cursor).

Comment: Works great, thanks! Is there any way to get rid of the go vet warnings "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields"?

Comment: @TommyF, to get rid of the "composite literal uses unkeyed fields" warnings you can simply add the field names to the initialization of the bson elements contained in the bson.D documents, i.e. 
```
pipeline := bson.A{
    bson.D{{
        Key: "$project",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "foo", Value: 1},
            {Key: "nrOfBars", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "$size", Value: "$bar"},
            }},
        },
    }},
}
```